# How to pass an input variable to another def?

Tags: python, input

```
        def main():
           selectionvalid = False
           print("Welcome to virtue vending machine!")
           print("Machine only takes $1 bills")
           table()
           while True:
               user = input("Select your choice:")
               if user == 'A1':
                   selectionvalid = True
                   print("Snickers: $.89")
                   change = bills() - a1
               elif user == 'A2':
                   print("M&Ms: $1.39")
                   change = bills() - a2
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'A3':
                   print("M&Ms: $1.39")
                   change = bills() - a2
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'B1':
                   print("Lays: $.50")
                   change = bills() - a3
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'B2':
                   print("Doritos: $.50")
                   change = bills() - a3
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'B3':
                   print("Cheetos: $1.49")
                   change = bills() - a5
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'C1':
                   print("TicTac: $1.04")
                   change = bills() - a6
                   selectionvalid = True
               elif user == 'C2':
                   selectionvalid = True
                   print("Starburst: $.79")
                   change = bills() - a7
               elif user == 'C3':
                   selectionvalid = True
                   print("Skittles: $2.49")
                   change = bills() - a8
               else:
                   print("Item not available.")
                   print("Please, select your choice again:")
               if selectionvalid == True:
                   print("Your change is:$", format(change, '.2f'))
                   message()
                   break
               return selectionvalid

        def bills():
           totals = 0 
           bills = int(input("Insert your bills:$"))
           while bills > 4:
            print("Please, enter less than $4")
            bills = int(input("Insert your bills:$"))
           else:
            print("You've inserted $",bills,"dollars")
            return bills


        def message():
            print("Your,",,"is dispensed below!")
            print("Thank you! Come Again!")
```

I'm trying to get the user input selection to show up to def message() Is there another way to condense the code from the if-elif-else to something more like a loop? I've heard about dictionary and lists, but that seems too complicated for this I think. 
For example:
"Your 'snicker' is dispensed below"
"You 'Kitkat' is dispensed below"

Thanks

Comment: Embrace dictionaries and lists, they are the everyday fare of Python programming.

Answer (score 1):

How's a dictionary more complicated than what you already have? A dictionary will clean up a lot of your code and get ride of 1/3 of the lines, mostly the `elif`s

```
vendingdict = {"A1": ["Snickers", 0.89],
               "A2": ["M&Ms", 1.39],
               "A3": ["Lays", 0.50]}
def main():
    global myselection
    while True:
        myselection=input("Welcome to virtue vending machine!\nMachine only takes $1 bills\nSelect your choice:\n")
        try:
            if vendingdict[myselection] != None:
                break
        except KeyError:
            print("\nPlease input valid selection\n")
            continue

def bills():
    while True:
        try:
            cashin = int(input("Insert your bills: $"))
        except ValueError:
            print("Please insert valid tender!")
            continue
        cashout = 0
        if cashin>=vendingdict[myselection][1]:
            cashout = cashin - vendingdict[myselection][1]
            print("Your change is $%.2f" % cashout)
            print("Your %s is below!" % vendingdict[myselection][0])
            break
        else:
            print("Insufficient money, please insert more.")
            print(cashin)
            cashin = 0
            continue


main()
bills()
```

Comment: Using what I got, how would you put the user inside message()? I tried to return the value but it doesn't work. Dictionary seemed complicated to me because the index.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure of what you mean by putting user inside of message()...

The dictionary is simply a look-up table. 

The nomenclature is `dictionary[key]` where `dictionary` is the variable that your dictionary is under and `[key]` is one of the lookups that has values assigned to it. You can assign any valid python types.

When you call for a key from a dictionary like `dictionary[key]` you are returned the value assigned to that key.

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just send the user input selection to `message()` as a parameter? Maybe create a dictionary `products` with user inputs as keys and products as values. Then `message(products[userInput])`.